2D plane of dependent variables and its relation to the plane of those independent variables
I am solving AoPs Intermedia Algebra book, and one of the questions has the following answer snippet. I am not posting entire answer from the book due to copyright reasons. To answer my question, you don't need the rest anyways. The answer in the book is:

Let $u = x - 2$ and $v = y - 2$. Then the equation becomes $\left|
 \left| u \right| - 1 \right| + \left| \left| v \right| - 1 \right| =
 1$. Again, we see that in the $uv$-plane, if the point $(u,v)$
satisfies this equation, then so do the points $(u,-v)$, $(-u,v)$, and
$(-u,-v)$. Hence, we may take the points that satisfy $u \ge 0$ and $v
 \ge 0$, and then reflect over the $u$- and $v$-axes. (Note that this
is equivalent to reflecting over the lines $x = 2$ and $y = 2$ in the
$xy$-plane.)

And my question is about the following line in this answer:

(Note that this is equivalent to reflecting over the lines =2 and
=2 in the -plane.)

I don't understand this. How is reflecting over the $u-$ and $v-$ axis in the $uv$-plane, equivalent to reflecting over the lines $x = 2$ and $y = 2$ in the $xy$ plane? Could you please explain the concept and logic as to why this is true.

This transformation is a translation which is essentially a change of origin. So you're moving the $x$ and $y$ so that origin is now at $(2,2)$.
